# Fake proof that $\zeta (1)=\gamma$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-zeta, fake-proofs, euler-mascheroni-constant

The following proof is fake, but I have no idea why it's not right (I know it's paradoxical, since $\zeta (1)$ diverges):
$$\begin{align*}\zeta (1)&=\dfrac{2\zeta (1)}{2}\\&=\dfrac{\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\zeta (1+x)+\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\zeta (1-x)}{2}\\&\overset{!}{=}\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\zeta (1+x)+\zeta (1-x)}{2}\\&=\gamma\approx 0.577.\end{align*}$$

Tannery's theorem is of the form $a\implies b$. Here, I did it the other way around: $b\implies a$. So, that's not equivalent (but is close) to Tannery's theorem. Where is the mistake? I suspect it's the "$!$", but which theorem does it refer to?

Comment: I think the limit $\lim_{s \to 1} \zeta(s)$ does not exists.

Comment: It's not right because the limits you refer to don't exist, so you can't use the usual theorems on them

Comment: To emphasize:  **IF** $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$ **AND** $\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = M$ **THEN** $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n + y_n) = L + M$.

If you cannot verify the two hypotheses, then you are not justified in using the conclusion.

Comment: How do you define $\zeta (1)$

Comment: The Cauchy' sprincipal value of $\zeta(1)$ is indeed $\gamma$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the rule $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n$ here because the limits do not exist. Like that you could create all kinds of wrong results ($\infty - \infty$ can be anything).

Comment: E.g., $\lim n+\lim(7-n)=7$.